# Bulk insert of multiple files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, append, bulkinsert

I have several chunks of a table in .dat files

I want to import all of these chuncks to a single sql server table.

To do it with one I do

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Tab
FROM 'C:\Data\1.dat'
WITH
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  );
```

but how to append to the table the rest of the .dat files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fire multiple `BULK INSERT` commands.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Tab
FROM 'C:\Data\1.dat'
WITH
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  );

BULK INSERT dbo.Tab
FROM 'C:\Data\2.dat'
WITH
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  );

...
```

Alternatively (and probably better for performance), use some other program to merge the files together first.